# Unable to resolve package error for .NET Framework, Version=v4.5.1

Tags: c#, nuget, asp.net-core-1.0, .net-core-rc2

I'm working on transitioning my `ASP.NET RC1` project to `Core.NET RC2`. When opening the project the package restore fails with the following errors:

> Errors in C:\Users\user\Documents\cwc_scaffold\project\CWC.xproj
>       Unable to resolve 'Glimpse (>= 2.0.0-beta1)' for '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1'.
>       Unable to resolve 'SharpGIS.NmeaParser (>= 1.5.1)' for '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1'.

I'm pretty new to `ASP` and `Nuget` so I'm not too sure what these errors mean.

**EDIT:** Here's my project.json file:

```
{
  "version": "0.9.0",
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true,
    "copyToOutput": [
      "appsettings.json"
    ]
  },
  "tooling": {
    "defaultNamespace": "COIN.Monitor"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Glimpse": "2.0.0-beta1",
    "Serilog": "1.5.14",
    "Microsoft.Tpl.Dataflow": "4.5.24",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WindowsServices": "1.0.0-rc2-final"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "net451": {
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.Web": "4.0.0.0"
      }
    }
  },
  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel"
  },
  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    }
  },
  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ],
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [
      "gulp clean",
      "gulp deploy-client",
      "webpack"
    ],
    "prebuild": [
      "npm run pre-build"
    ],
    "postpublish": [
      "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Both of those packages should support .Net 4.5.1. Could you post your project.json?

Comment: I've appended my project.json to the original post.

Comment: Restoring that works fine for me. Also, I don't see `SharpGIS.NmeaParser` there, are you sure the project.json and the error messages are correct?

Comment: The SharpGIS.NmeaParser is located in the project.json.lock file. I'm going to uninstall and reinstall everything to see if I missed a step during the RC2 installation process.

Answer (score 0):

Packages pulled in from Nuget will default to getting a `lowest` common denominator version for dependent packages/libraries.

Possibly (?) you need later version of said packages?

So look at the nuget page for installed packages and for each of the individual packaged pulled in, check to see if their is a new version which could be installed or change the the dependency behavior to `Highest` or other setting which make sense.

Regardless you may need to experiment with the packages being pulled in to get it to work.

[image]